# How to work with existing html elements with Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm stuck in the position where I have to work with some pre-generated html elements. For example I have a list like this

```
<ul>
  <li class="product>
    <div class="name">product 1</div>
    <div class="price">$199</div>
  </li>
  <li class="product>
    <div class="name">product 2</div>
    <div class="price">$299</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Since the AngularJs has been talking all about dynamically generated content via js, I wonder if there is a way that I can loop through the pre-generated html elements to initialize the models?

Comment: The angular guys are working on a solution for what you want. But the solution is not independent of the server side. i.e it needs support from the server side. As of yet, there is no solution to pull out models from a pregenerated html.

Comment: Thank you, I was using Backbone.js and got a bit tired of writing too much code and was looking around. I wonder if I will run into the same issue with Ember or Knockout :(

Comment: The thing with this is that there is no solution ( as far as I can tell yet ) which fills out a Model in client side MVC from a prerendered html. This is probably one of the holy grail of client side MVC's. The first one to probably crack that will be at a huge advantage.

Comment: Hi Ganaraj, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe with backbone js you can kinda loop through existing elements to manually generate a model object and add to the collection. I think it's also possible with knockoutjs as well.

Comment: Yes, you can. But if you are planning on doing this manually by writing that piece of the code yourself, you can do that with angular as well. The hard part is to extract the template out of the rendered html and use that template to produce another item. If you consider the example you provided above - Backbone, Knockout or angular can extract the information out of the li - But can you ( generically ) without prior knowledge of the template produce a third item? THAT is the challenge.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Normally I used to have to manage 2 templates (1 for the server-side code and 1 for the js framework which is very troublesome)

Comment: See Sten Hougaard's 2nd comment on the ngRepeat API page (you'll have to hit that "Load more comments" button at the bottom, and you may first need to reload the API page to see any Disqus comments).  He claims he was able to add a model dynamically using jQuery, and AngularJS recognized it.